# Mysql Syntax Error in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, mysql-error-1064

> I am trying to define relationship between tables using foreign keys 
>   in drupal 7. I used hook_schema and hook_update function to define and
>   update the schema. I am getting following errors.

```
$schema['relationship] = array(
  'description' => 'The table for employee organisation relationship',
  'fields' => array(
      'rid' => array(
          'description' => 'The primary Identifier for a Relationship.',
          'type' => 'serial',
          'unsigned' => TRUE,
          'not null' => TRUE,
      ),
      'uid' => array(
          'description' => 'The primary Identifier for User/Employee',
          'type' => 'int',
          'unsigned' => TRUE,
          'not null' => FALSE,
          'default' => 0,
      ),
      'oid' => array(
          'description' => 'The department Identifier of employee employed',
          'type' => 'int',
          'unsigned' => TRUE,
          'not null' => FALSE,
          'default' => 0,
  ),
  'indexes' => array(
      'uid' => array('uid'),
     'oid' => array('oid'),
  ),    
 'foreign keys' => array(
     'uid' => array(
         'table' => 'users',
          'columns' => array('uid' => 'uid')
     ),
      'oid' => array(
       'table' => 'organization',
         'columns' => array('oid' => 'oid')
   ),
 ),
  'primary key' => array('rid'),
  )
);
```

> Failed: PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access
>   violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'DEFAULT NULL ) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
>   COMMENT 'The table for' at line 5: CREATE TABLE
>   {organisation} ( `id` INT unsigned NOT NULL
>   auto_increment COMMENT 'The primary Identifier for a Relationship.',
>   `uid` INT unsigned NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'The primary Identifier for
>   User/Employee', `oid` INT unsigned NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'The
>   department Identifier of employee employed', `primary key` DEFAULT
>   NULL ) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COMMENT 'The table
>   for employee organisation relationship'; Array ( ) in
>   db_create_table() (line 2717 of
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\tutumaudit\includes\database\database.inc).

Answer (score 0):

> Well I sorted it out myself. I put those keys under the fields array.
>   That was damn stupid and i needed 2 hours to find this out. The final
>   code is below:

```
$schema['relationship] = array(
  'description' => 'The table for employee organisation relationship',
  'fields' => array(
      'rid' => array(
          'description' => 'The primary Identifier for a Relationship.',
          'type' => 'serial',
          'unsigned' => TRUE,
          'not null' => TRUE,
      ),
      'uid' => array(
          'description' => 'The primary Identifier for User/Employee',
          'type' => 'int',
          'unsigned' => TRUE,
          'not null' => FALSE,
          'default' => 0,
      ),
      'oid' => array(
          'description' => 'The department Identifier of employee employed',
          'type' => 'int',
          'unsigned' => TRUE,
          'not null' => FALSE,
          'default' => 0,
  ),  
  ),
'indexes' => array(
      'uid' => array('uid'),
     'oid' => array('oid'),
  ),    
 'foreign keys' => array(
     'uid' => array(
         'table' => 'users',
          'columns' => array('uid' => 'uid')
     ),
      'oid' => array(
       'table' => 'organization',
         'columns' => array('oid' => 'oid')
   ),
 ),
  'primary key' => array('rid'),
);
```